# Enable and disable button through remove attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to write a program to enable and disable button on checkbox through **remove attribute** jQuery code.

I tried it but it didn't work.

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#myCheckBox').on('change', function() {
     var x = $(this).attr('value');
     if (x == 'on') {
       $('#myButton').removeAttr('disabled');
     } else if (x == undefined) {
       $('#myButton').attr('disabled');
     }
   });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="myCheckBox">
  I agree with terms and conditions
  <input type="checkbox" id="myCheckBox" />
</label>
<br />
<br />
<input type="button" id="myButton" value="Submit" disabled />
```

I am a beginner in jQuery, please comment below for any query.

Comment: Don't query the value of the checkbox, use `.prop('checked')` instead.

Comment: `x==on` ??? are you sure

Comment: use this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pandeyvishal1986/kpu35kqm/#&togetherjs=JoMqs8FyNn)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.is(':checked')` instead of checing the value. also replace :

```
$('#myButton').attr('disabled'); //Get the value
```

By :

```
$('#myButton').attr('disabled','disabled'); //Set the value
```

To set the value.

**NOTE :** you could do this using `prop()` instead :

```
$("#myButton").prop('disabled', !$(this).is(':checked'));
```

Hope this helps.

**`attr()`/`removeAttr()` Snippet :**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#myCheckBox').on('change',function(){
    if( $(this).is(':checked') ){
      $('#myButton').removeAttr('disabled');
    }else{
      $('#myButton').attr('disabled','disabled');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="myCheckBox">
  I agree with terms and conditions
  <input type="checkbox" id="myCheckBox" />
</label>
<br />
<br />
<input type="button" id="myButton" value="Submit" disabled />
```

**`prop()` Snippet :**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#myCheckBox').on('change',function(){
    $("#myButton").prop('disabled', !$(this).is(':checked'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="myCheckBox">
  I agree with terms and conditions
  <input type="checkbox" id="myCheckBox" />
</label>
<br />
<br />
<input type="button" id="myButton" value="Submit" disabled />
```

Comment: You should use `prop()` instead of `attr()` to toggle based on a value. http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: _I want to write a program to enable and disable button on checkbox through remove attribute_, i'm trying just to answer the question.

Comment: You're trying to answer the question however you should be directing the OP to use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`. As jQuery states (emphasis mine): _To retrieve and change DOM properties such as the checked, selected, or **disabled** state of form elements, use the .prop() method._

Comment: @j08691 no, it was directed at the person answering.

Answer (score 1):

You're over thinking this a bit. First use `.prop()` not `.attr()`. Second, just set the disabled property to the opposite of the checkbox's state with:

```
  $('#myCheckBox').on('change', function() {
    $('#myButton').prop('disabled', !$(this).is(':checked'));
  })
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myCheckBox').on('change', function() {
    $('#myButton').prop('disabled', !$(this).is(':checked'));
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="myCheckBox">
  I agree with terms and conditions
  <input type="checkbox" id="myCheckBox" />
</label>
<br />
<br />
<input type="button" id="myButton" value="Submit" disabled />
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `attr('value')` use `this.checked` instead to get checkbox status. Then use `prop()` method to set button status like following.

```js
$('#myCheckBox').on('change', function() {
    $('#myButton').prop('disabled', !this.checked); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="myCheckBox">
  I agree with terms and conditions
  <input type="checkbox" id="myCheckBox" />
</label>
<br />
<br />
<input type="button" id="myButton" value="Submit" disabled />
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with the code:

1. `var x = $(this).attr('value');` will **always** return the value of the checkbox, whether it's checked or not. I fyou want to check its checked state, it's the `checked` property on the element (`this.checked` in your handler, or `$(this).prop("checked")` if you want more jQuery).
2. `$('#myButton').attr('disabled');` is a no-op: It **reads** the value of the attribute, and then throws it away. To *set* it, you'd do `$('#myButton').attr('disabled', 'disabled');`

Note that using `prop('disabled', trueOrFalse)` is the preferred way to set/clear the disabled state.

```
$('#myCheckBox').on('change', function() {
    $("#myButton").prop('disabled', !this.checked);
});
```

But since you specifically said you wanted to use the attribute:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#myCheckBox').on('change', function() {
     if (this.checked) {
       $('#myButton').removeAttr('disabled');
     } else {
       $('#myButton').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
     }
   });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="myCheckBox">
  I agree with terms and conditions
  <input type="checkbox" id="myCheckBox" />
</label>
<br />
<br />
<input type="button" id="myButton" value="Submit" disabled />
```

But here's an example of using the property, which is really the way to go:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#myCheckBox').on('change', function() {
     $('#myButton').prop('disabled', !this.checked);
   });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="myCheckBox">
  I agree with terms and conditions
  <input type="checkbox" id="myCheckBox" />
</label>
<br />
<br />
<input type="button" id="myButton" value="Submit" disabled />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `is` method of `checkbox`. Use this JS [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pandeyvishal1986/kpu35kqm/#&togetherjs=JoMqs8FyNn):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#myCheckBox').on('change', function() {
     var x = $(this).attr('value');
     if($(this).is(':checked')) {
       $('#myButton').prop('disabled','');
     } else {
       $('#myButton').prop('disabled','disabled');
     }
   });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#myCheckBox').on('change', function() {
     if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
       $('#myButton').removeAttr('disabled');
     }else{
       $('#myButton').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
     }
   });
 });
```